# How to open generated PDF in MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I do AJAX call to generate PDF from crystal report.

Problem is , how to open PDF directly.

Below is my stuff. It looks, pdf is created but, it just return to view and not able to open PDF.

Please guide me.

Code:

```
      public ActionResult CreatePDF(string paramValue)
         {
          DataTable dt = new DataTable();
          DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("FieldName");
          dt.Columns.Add(dcinitial);
          DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
          dr[0]=paramValue;
          dt.Rows.Add(dr);
          ReportDocument oRpt = new ReportDocument();            
         string path = Server.MapPath("~/PDFDocs/crystalreport.rpt");
        oRpt.Load(path);
        oRpt.SetDataSource(dt);



        MemoryStream oStream = new MemoryStream();
        oStream = (MemoryStream)oRpt.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        string fileName = "Report";            
        Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);                       
        Response.BinaryWrite(oStream.ToArray());
        Response.End();
        return View();
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't write to the `Response` in the controller.  Aside from coupling issues and testability, it's confusing the functionality of that controller action.  This code is trying to *both* write the file to the response *and* return the view.

Instead, just return the file, which you can do directly from the stream:

```
return File(oStream, "application/pdf", fileName);
```

However...

> I do AJAX call

That's going to complicate things a bit.  Ideally this *wouldn't* be an AJAX call.  This is because AJAX doesn't handle "files" in a way you might think.  [There are options](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4545311/328193), but it would probably be easier to make this a normal page-level request so the browser can handle the file natively.

Since it's returning a file and not a view, the browser won't unload the current page.  (Unless it's configured to *display* the file instead of save it, though there isn't much you can do about that.  The server-side code is properly suggesting that the browser *save* the file by providing a `Content-Disposition` header.)

Comment: ok, will it be fine even though, i call this action using AJAX ?

Comment: @Dhaval: I just added some more details to the answer around that :)  The short version is that you *might* be able to handle a file download through AJAX (likely with the use of a plugin somewhere), but ideally it wouldn't be an AJAX call.